# Using both __setattr__ and descriptors for a python class

Tags: python, attributes, setter, descriptor

I'm writing a python class that uses `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` to provide custom attribute access.

However, some attributes can't be handled in a generic way, so I was hoping to use descriptors for those.

A problem arises in that for a descriptor, the descriptor's `__get__` will be invoked in favour of the instances `__getattr__`, but when assigning to an attribute, `__setattr__` will be invoked in favour of the descriptors `__set__`.

An example:

```
class MyDesc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print "MyDesc.__get__"
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print "MyDesc.__set__"
        self.val = value

class MyObj(object):

    foo = MyDesc()

    def __init__(self, bar):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'names', dict(
            bar=bar,
        ))
        object.__setattr__(self, 'new_names', dict())

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print "MyObj.__setattr__ for %s" % name
        self.new_names[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "MyObj.__getattr__ for %s" % name

        if name in self.new_names:
            return self.new_names[name]

        if name in self.names:
            return self.names[name]

        raise AttributeError(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    o = MyObj('bar-init')

    o.bar = 'baz'
    print o.bar

    o.foo = 'quux'
    print o.foo
```

prints:

```
MyObj.__setattr__ for bar
MyObj.__getattr__ for bar
baz
MyObj.__setattr__ for foo
MyDesc.__get__
None
```

The descriptor's `__set__` is never called.

Since the `__setattr__` definition isn't just overriding behaviour for a limited set of names, there's no clear place that it can defer to `object.__setattr__`

Is there a recommended way to have assigning to attributes use the descriptor, if available, and `__setattr__` otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**

Revisiting this answer more than 10 years later, I realized that I included a recipe, but did not explain the outstanding behavior the OP met: a descritpor's `__get__` is called before an instance's `__getattr__`, yes. But the actual converse to `__setattr__` is `__getattribute__`, not `__getattr__`. Inside `object`'s `__getattribute__` is where is the code with the search order for attributes in first place, and the code responsible for calling a descriptor's `__get__` itself. `__getattr__` is called by the code in `__getattribute__` itself as a last resort, after inspecting any possible descriptors, `__slots__`, and the instance's `__dict__`.

**original answer: just do what the OP wants to achieve**

I think I'd approach this by having a mechanism to automatically mark which are the
descriptors in each class, and wrap the `__setattr__` in a way that it'd call
object's normal behavior for those names.

This can be easily achieved with a metaclass (and a decorator for `__setattr__`

```
def setattr_deco(setattr_func):
    def setattr_wrapper(self, attr, value):
        if attr in self._descriptors:
            return object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        return setattr_func(self, attr, value)
    return setattr_wrapper

class MiscSetattr(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        descriptors = set()
        for key, obj in dct.items():
            if key == "__setattr__":
                dct[key] = setattr_deco(obj)
            elif hasattr(obj, "__get__"):
                descriptors.add(key)
        dct["_descriptors"] = descriptors
        return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
    
# and use MiscSetattr as metaclass for your classes
```

Comment: I may be not following this, but why is `__setattr__` called for the descriptors? Do we not want `__set__` to be called?

Comment: `__setattr__` is how one can customize attribute writing access to any class - all attribute setting go through it, _even_ when the target attribute is a descriptor. Actually, calling the checking for a data descriptor and calling its `__set__`  is **performed** by the default `__setattr__` code in the `object` class: Python is very consistent in this way, providing several points where one can customize things like attribute access, but in a way once you choose which way you will customize, you can do that in a single place. (No having to customize _both_ `__setattr__`  _and_ a  `__set__`.

Answer (score 5):

One of possible ways:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    print "MyObj.__setattr__ for %s" % name
    for cls in self.__class__.__mro__ + (self, ):
        if name in cls.__dict__:
            return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    print 'New name', name, value
    self.new_names[name] = value
```

It checks if name already defined in class, base classes or instance and then it calls `object.__setattr__` which will execute descriptor `__set__`.

Another way:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    print "MyObj.__setattr__ for %s" % name
    try:
        object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    except AttributeError:
        print 'New name', name, value
        self.new_names[name] = value
    else:
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

But it will call descriptor's `__get__`.

P.S.

I'm not sure about need to check all `__mro__` members since `MyObj` will contain inherited class members in `__dict__`.

Maybe `for cls in (self.__class__, self):...` will be enough.

Comment: You're second way won't work. In my example, you're allowed to set new attributes on the object that didn't already exist, and this method would disallow that.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, I think it works like your's. Take a look http://ideone.com/HMBcc. Maybe I'm misssing something.

Comment: If I did `o.quux = 3`, then `o.__dict__['quux']` would be set instead of `o.new_names['quux']`

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, I can't reproduce. What is your Python version? http://ideone.com/XXAR5

Comment: There is a problem though, if `__get__` might sometimes raise AttributeError